# String.Format for creating regex patterns

Tags: c#, regex, string.format

a quick hand would be much appreciated.
I'm trying to make a small algorithm to input the text from a text box into a regex expression. As follows:

```
    string bar = String.Format(@"^{0}*(q*x|x*q)*", foo.Text);
```

the regex class is passed the bar variable above and initialized when the event is fired. However, it only returns hits when there is repeating text. E.G bb in the textbox returns all results that begin with b, and 1b returns matches on every word.

??? is there something wrong with my regex or my logic? (or both! :P)

*EDIT* i am attempting to match a list of strings loaded from a text file. all words that contain both a q and an x at least once, beginning with the letters in the text box. examples:
arquifoux
benzofuroquinoxaline
benzoquinoxaline
disquixote
equiaxe

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: Please provides the string which you are matching with this regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
string bar = String.Format(@"^{0}.*?(q.*?x|x.*?q).*", foo.Text);
```

The `.` matches any character.
The question mark in `.*?` just makes the match non-greedy (ie the 'q' will match the first q it finds), although in your case they're not really necessary.

Your previous, 'q*', matches "0 or more q characters".

You could further improve your regex:

```
string bar = String.Format(@"^{0}[a-z]*?(q[a-z]*?x|x[a-z]*?q)[a-z]*", foo.Text);
```

Which only matches lowercase letters. (you could feed in the case insensitive flag to your regex to have it match any case).

Comment: *palmface* yes, regex fail. thanks for correcting my stupidity!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your regex is incorrect.
I think you are missing some periods (.) in there before the *'s

If you break down what you have: `^{0}*(q*x|x*q)*` that is saying:

```
^{0}* <-- starts with 0 or more of whatever the text box had.
(q*x|x*q)* <-- then contains 0 or more of this pattern.
```

Since you are asking for "0 or more", it basically matches anything. Entering "bb" would appear to work because that would make the starting regex: `^bb*` which breaks down to:

```
^b <-- starts with 1 letter 'b'
b* <-- followed by 0 or more letter 'b's
```

---

I think what you wanted was:

```
^{0}.*(q.*x|x.*q)+
```

Which breaks down to:

```
^{0} <-- starts with 1 of whatever my text box had
.* <-- then 0 or more of anything
(q.*x|x.*q)+ <-- then 1 or more of q + anything + x, or x + anything + q
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some matches in the regex to match characters between your a, q and x. For word matching, you will want this (\w instead of . to limit to word characters only)

```
^{0}\w*(q\w*x|x\w*q)
```

Probably not required here for you here, but it is good to use Regex.Escape the escaped your user entered text before inserting it directly into a regex statement

Answer (score 0):

```
string bar = string.Format("^(\w+\s+)*{0}\w+(q\w*x|x\w*q)+.*", Regex.Escape(Regfoo.Text));
```

This should:

1. Match the line beginning. ^
2. Match any or no full words preceding. (\w+\s+)*
3. Match the designated text occuring once at the beginning of a word {0}.
4. Match the remainder of the word containg q then x or x then q. \w+(q\w*x|x\w*q)+
5. Match the any more characters. .*